# File not found but I think it's there

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, yolo

I am trying to implement Yolov8 on my custom dataset in TensorFlow. I am working in Google Colab. The data is segregated into training and validation set using the following statement:

```
num_val = int(len(xml_files) * SPLIT
# Split the dataset into train and validation sets
val_data = data.take(num_val)
train_data = data.skip(num_val)
```

After that the image and the annotations are loaded and also apply the required preprocessing as:

```
def load_image(image_paths):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_paths)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    return image


def load_dataset(image_paths, classes, bbox):
    # Read Image
    image = load_image(image_paths)
    bounding_boxes = {
        "classes": tf.cast(classes, dtype=tf.float32),
        "boxes": bbox,
    }
    return {"images": tf.cast(image, tf.float32), "bounding_boxes": bounding_boxes}
augmenter = keras.Sequential(
    layers=[
        keras_cv.layers.RandomSharpness(1, [0,255]),
        keras_cv.layers.AutoContrast([0,255]),
        keras_cv.layers.JitteredResize(
            target_size=(640, 640), scale_factor=(0.75, 1.3), bounding_box_format="xyxy"
        ),
    ]
)
train_ds = train_data.map(load_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 4)
train_ds = train_ds.ragged_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
train_ds = train_ds.map(augmenter, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

val_ds = val_data.map(load_dataset, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.shuffle(BATCH_SIZE * 4)
val_ds = val_ds.ragged_batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
val_ds = val_ds.map(augmenter, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Now, I want to visualize the dataset but unable to visualize using following code:

```
def visualize_dataset(inputs, value_range, rows, cols, bounding_box_format):
    inputs = next(iter(inputs.take(1)))
    images, bounding_boxes = inputs["images"], inputs["bounding_boxes"]
    visualization.plot_bounding_box_gallery(
        images,
        value_range=value_range,
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        y_true=bounding_boxes,
        scale=5,
        font_scale=0.7,
        bounding_box_format=bounding_box_format,
        class_mapping=class_mapping,
    )
 
 
visualize_dataset(
    train_ds, bounding_box_format="xyxy", value_range=(0, 255), rows=2, cols=2
)
 
visualize_dataset(
    val_ds, bounding_box_format="xyxy", value_range=(0, 255), rows=2, cols=2
)
```

But I get an error that image_0329 is not present. However, the image is present in "images: folder in google drive. The detailed error is as follows:

```
Error: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_3_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} /content/drive/MyDrive/images/images/image_0329; No such file or directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name: 
Error: {{function_node __wrapped__IteratorGetNext_output_types_3_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} /content/drive/MyDrive/images/images/image_0001; No such file or directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name:
```

Anyone can guide me and resolve this issue please.

Comment: You have a subfolder called `images` in your folder `images`?

Comment: Maybe the file ending is missing? It's hard to guess without seeing the folder structure.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393102/xdurch0) yes I have subfolder images in main folder images